# How to get 12.04's login screen (lightdm) to display the shutdown menu like 10.04 when the computer's physical power button is pressed?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen

In Ubuntu 10.04 while at the login screen (gdm), when the computer's physical power button was pressed a screen popped up that offered options on shutting down the system (shutdown, restart, cancel, ...) along with a 60 second countdown that when elapsed would shutdown the computer.

This is useful if you have a system that you use mainly as a server and occasionally as a desktop.  When used as a server, one could press the computer's physical power button and 60 seconds later the system powered down,

Is there a way turn this behavior on or emulate it in lightdm?  Or is it a bug [ACPI events to shutdown/reboot don't generate a popup like after logging in](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/915382)?

I found a work around, [Use PC's power button while screen is locked](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1669946&highlight=login%20shutdown%20%20power%20button).  However this is more heavy handed that what I am looking for.  It shuts down the system immediately after the computer's physical power button is pressed in all cases, logged in or not.  It also does not give the option to abort the pending shutdown in the case the computer's power button was pressed accidentally.